# ReLU in Deep Neural Net trained with Contrastive Divergence

Tags: python, neural-network, unsupervised-learning

I am trying to adopt the code for Deep Learning with Contrastive Divergence from http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/DBN.html#dbn to work with real valued input data instead of binary as described in the tutorial.  I understand the way to do this is to switch from a sigmoid activation function to a Rectified Linear Unit (ReLU) but I have some questions about doing this from a practical perspective...

1. Can I simply use a ReLU defined as max(0,x) or will I need a NReLU defined as max(0,x+N) where N is the Gaussian noise?  If a NReLU is recommended what is the proper way to compute N for a sample?
2. If I use a ReLU (or NReLU) do I need to modify my free-energy function which for sigmoid units is the python code...

   ```
   def free_energy(self, v_sample):
       wx_b = T.dot(v_sample, self.W) + self.hbias
       vbias_term = T.dot(v_sample, self.vbias)
       hidden_term = T.sum(T.log(1 + T.exp(wx_b)), axis=1)
       return -hidden_term - vbias_term
   ```

From what I've seen in papers, the above looks like it will practically work for both sigmoid and ReLUs.  If this is not correct I'd appreciate a posting of the modified code to work for ReLUs.